# Configure membase in php

Tags: php, configuration, membase

I have installed membase in my system,but i don't know how to configure membase in php.
And how to add two server and configure in membase,how to add cluster and nodes.
How to configure membase client in php?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the existing PHP Memcache client to access your Membase cluster.  I recommend PECL/Memcached as the PHP client of choice, but it does require you to install a couple more components (libmemcached, for example).

If that's too much work to get started, you can always use PECL/Memcache just to make sure you are able to connect to your Membase cluster and get/put data.

Once you have successfully installed Membase, simply go to http://server-url:8091 to access a graphical admin interface.  It is simple to figure out how to start a cluster and have another server join the cluster as a node through it.